# complete existing mesh by "rounding it off"?

Tags: modeling

I have this Spark AR face mesh and I want to simply finish it off to create the rest of a human head. It doesn't need to look very good. I'd like to hear how you would approach this. I started by doing some edge loops and extruding, then scaling, and I got a decent shape but at the end I was left with a loop that I wanted to collapse into a single vertex and couldn't figure that out. Anyway, suggestions welcome!

[image]

Comment: do you mean that you want to fill the hole that is behind, with a flat surface?

Comment: I would like to fill it with a rounded shape

Comment: you can try Bridge Edge Loops... make 2 simetrical selections of edges on that border, maybe 12 on the left and 12 on the right, then Edge > Bridge Edge Loops and use Interpolation > Blend Surface and something like 10 cuts... then use same tool or Grid Fill to fill top and bottom holes... try a few times and other edges till you get some good settings, then drag with Proportional Editing to give it a better shape